# Orthogonal lightlike (null) vectors are colinear

Tags: linear-algebra, semi-riemannian-geometry

I want to prove the statement that in a Lorentzian vector space, i.e., vector space with a scalar product whose index is 1, if lightlike vectors are orthogonal, then they are colinear. Equivalently, if lightlike vectors are linearly independent, then their scalar product is non-zero.

Can you give me an idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Take a unit timelike vector $v$ and write $V = v^\perp \oplus \Bbb R v$. Assume that $x= x_0+av$ and $y=y_0+bv$ are lightlike and orthogonal (written according to this decomposition). Since $v$ is timelike, $v^\perp$ is a spacelike hyperplane, and so $x_0$ and $y_0$ are spacelike too. We have three relations: $$\langle x_0,x_0\rangle = a^2,\quad\langle y_0,y_0\rangle = b^2\quad\mbox{and}\quad \langle x_0,y_0\rangle = ab. $$ Then $$\langle bx_0-ay_0,bx_0-ay_0\rangle = b^2a^2 -2baab +a^2b^2=0. $$ But $bx_0-ay_0$ is spacelike, and the above then implies that $bx_0-ay_0=0$. Also note that $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$, since $x$ and $y$ are lightlike. With this $$by-ax= by_0 +bav- ax_0 -abv=0, $$and so $\{x,y\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: How did you came up with the three relations?

Comment: They are $\langle x,x\rangle = 0$, $\langle y,y\rangle = 0$, and $\langle x,y\rangle = 0$, respectively.

Comment: Here is what I get: 
$$
\begin{align*}
0=m(x,x) &= m(x_0+av, x_0+av) \\
&= m(x_0, x_0) + 2am(x_0, v) + a^2m(v,v) \\
&= m(x_0, x_0)+2am(x_0,v)+a^2,
\end{align*}
$$
where $m$ is the lorentzian inner product. So from here, I really don't see how we end up with just $m(x_0, x_0)  = a^2$.

Comment: You need to pay very close attention to what is happening here: First, $x_0$ is orthogonal to $v$. Second, $v$ is unit timelike.

Comment: I bow down to you, master.